# A little help with trying to time an async task

Tags: android

Situation: I would like to pull a network resource (a file), display it for 30 seconds, then load the next file. While displaying the initial file for 30 seconds, I'd like to preload the next file.

Question: Should I be using concurrent threads with a lock (like a linked blocking queue?) or a handler? Or something I'm missing?

Currently I have the onCreate call an asynctask that has a for loop which iterates through an array of paths for the files one at a time, which then calls the next asynctask (inside the for loop) which downloads the file from that path and then in the onPostExecute assigns the file to the UI view.

This works but I am unable to setup timing where the first file loads in the UI view then 30 seconds later the next file loads in the UI view and so on... Right now it loads the files fine but the 1st may take 40 seconds to display and the 2nd 25 seconds and the 3rd 60.

(FYI, the files are uniform size and only take 5~15 sec to load)

Here's a general example (non compile-able):

onCreate(){
new firstAsynchTask().execute(filePaths[]);
}

```
private class firstAsynchTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(String[]... x) {
        try {
            for(int i = 0; x[0] != null && i < x.length; i++)
            {
                long startT = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(x[0][i].isFile())
                {
                    SmbFile g = new SmbFile(x[0][i].getPath());
                    new secondAsynchTask().execute(g);
                    long TimeNow = (System.currentTimeMillis() - 30000);
                    if(startT > TimeNow)
                    {
                      try {
                           Thread.sleep(startT - TimeNow);
                       }  catch (IOException e) {
                                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                       e.printStackTrace();}
                    }
                }
                if(i == x.length - 1)
                {
                    i = 0;
                }

            }
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return null;
        }   
    }

private class SecondAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, Drawable> {
    protected File doInBackground(File... x) {

        SomeType FileTemp = new File();
        try {
            long startT = System.currentTimeMillis();
            FileTemp = (get streamed file);
            long TimeNow = (System.currentTimeMillis() - 30000);
            if(startT > TimeNow)
            {
               Thread.sleep(startT - TimeNow);
               return FileTemp;
            }
            else
            {
                return FileTemp;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

   protected void onPostExecute(File result) {
        if(result != null)
        {
        FileView centerFile = (FileView) findViewById(R.id.FileView1);
        centerFile.setFile(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple producer-consumer approach would be sufficient for what you need. I would have an array of URLs that point to your network resource with a synchronised access. A single AsyncTask would be enough to pop a single URL off the queue, download and display it. How you will re-invoke the task depends on you: you can display downloaded resource and at the same time run task, putting downloaded resource to some temporary placeholder (a Drawable member field for example). Have a timer that every 30 seconds just puts temporary resource to the display and runs download/cache task again.

Of course this is a very simple solutions without handling cases when your task haven't finished in 30 seconds time frame, etc.

Another approach would be to have a boolean object that you will set to true every 30 seconds. Your AsyncTask runs, downloads image and on onPostExecute checks if previously mentioned boolean is set to true, if yes - displays image, sets flag to false and finishes. If flag is false then it enters a loop that sleeps for, say, 200ms and checks condition again, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I like the solution of adding a temp file to hold the file in a placeholder until the timing is right, however how do I pass a variable from the 2nd asynctask to the 1st?

Comment: The reason I ask is because all the code in the 1st task is handled in the doInBackground so it cannot reach UI variables.

Comment: Do you really need seconds AsyncTask? You can do all the looping and downloading in a single AsyncTask so you won't have any timing issues.

Comment: I need the second task so I can sleep the loop but preload the next file while sleeping the loop. otherwise the loop will run through the iterations and in the case where it takes longer to download the file then the timer I have set, I will be unable to control that case. My first Anyctask should never complete unless I interrupt it. It will be an infinite loop with a break "if" clause.

Comment: OK, one way is to define both AsyncTasks inside you activity, thus both of them can access private/protected members of Activity (and use handler to access UI thread). That's the simplest way. But in your case I would re-think the strategy you are using and would move to [producer-consumer](http://book.javanb.com/java-threads-3rd/jthreads3-CHP-8-SECT-3.html) "pattern".

Comment: I'll look into the producer consumer as I've heard it a number of times... Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. Btw, the code you posted, you can still do it with a single AsyncTask. Create a timer that checks for a conditions and replaces current image with a new one + starts a new download task.

Comment: How is that possible to do in one asynctask? How could I update the UI without using onPostExecute and end the thread?